# Error with TikZ foreach iteration on changing tthe position

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to draw a series of shapes (circle in the example) and change the color and text to be inscribed. I can get that with the following code:

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames]{standalone}                           
%
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
  \foreach \k / \y / \z in {                                            
     SkyBlue/10/A,                                                      
     SteelBlue/7/B,                                                     
     Coral/4/C,                                                         
     SandyBrown/1/D                                                     
     } {                                                                
       \draw[fill=\k] (0, \y) circle (1cm) ;                            
                                                                        
       \node at (0, \y) {\small \z} ;                                   
  }                                                                     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following :

[image]

If I change the sequence to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]                           
  \foreach \y / \z / \k in {
     10/A/SkyBlue,
      7/B/SteelBlue,
      4/C/Coral,
      1/D/SandyBrown
     } {
       \draw[fill=\k] (0, \y) circle (1cm) ;

       \node at (0, \y) {\small \z} ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following error:

```
x.tex:17: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `SandyBrown '.
```

Are there any constraints about the variables used in `foreach`? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I think you just need a trailing comma on the color: `SandyBrown,` instead of `SandyBrown`. It wasn't a problem in the first example as the tailing space after the `D ` did not matter as that was just text, not something that needs to be looked up.

Comment: Since spaces are allowed in color names, these are not ignored. Line breaks will be converted into spaces. So, place the curly brace directly after `SandyBrown` or add a `%` or a `,` (as Peter Grill suggests) behind it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comments.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that removing the newline or using a `%` does solve the problem. But putting a `,` at the end gave me a black circle.